# npm not working on mac os x after installing node v0.8.15

Tags: node.js, osx-snow-leopard, npm

I've installed node successfully using the pkg file from nodejs.org (I can get the "*hello world*" app running). The **node.js** installation dialogue stated that npm was also installed, but I can't get it to run from the command line (I get "`-bash: npm: command not found`"). I've tried invoking it from the npm directory (`.npm/npm/1.1.32/package`) but get an error message:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Frank/.npm/npm/1.1.32/package/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
```

Any help would be much appreciated -- I'm new to node and not yet very good with Terminal. Thanks!

Comment: I notice that `usr/local/bin` contains a broken alias for npm. There is an install of npm in my `tmp` directory, but when I run it at that location I receive error messages about the paths (as noted above).

Comment: Both the `tmp` and `.npm` installs are producing the same error, which seems to be caused by an incorrect relative link in `module.js`:
    `module.js:340
        throw err;
              ^
    Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Frank/.npm/npm/1.1.32/package/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
        at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)`
fixing the links leads to a further cascade of similar errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've fixed the problem. It was a permissions issue. For some reason, my admin account did not have superuser permissions for several crucial locations; in particular, I lacked proper permissions for `usr/local/bin/lib` and `usr/local/bin/include`. Changing the permissions for these directories fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't have these folders. Hmm.

Comment: these are typically hidden from view (in the finder) to protect system files. you'll probably want to use terminal to make these changes.